# How to set the user_dump_dest parameter in oracle for SQL trace

Tags: oracle, database-administration

How to set the user_dump_dest parameter in oracle for SQL trace for the current session?

```
alter session set user_dump_dest="C:\TKprof\Trace";
```

Is giving me ther error:

> ORA-02096: specified initialization parameter is not modifiable with
>   this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
alter system set user_dump_dest = 'C:\TKprof\Trace' scope=both
```

The `DBA` or `ALTER SYSTEM` privilege is required.

Comment: I have none of the above priviledges

Comment: Ask it from your `DBA` or ask him to perform the work you want to do.